# How to define variable in system configuration field and update them in controller?

Tags: magento2, system.xml

In `system.xml` I've a field `'twilio/general/message'` which saves following message:

```
Use {{otp}} as otp to verify your mobile number.
```

In controller I'm getting field's value as

```
$message = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'twilio/general/message', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
        );
```

`{{otp}}` will be generated programatically in controller. How I can replace `{{otp}}` in `$message` with generated otp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my suggestion:

Create a custom function:

```
$message = "Use {{otp}} as otp to verify your mobile number.";

if(preg_match('/\{\{([a-z0-9_]+)\}\}/is', $message, $matches)) {
    //var_dump($matches);
    $message = str_replace('{{' . $matches[1] . '}}', '1234567', $message);

};

echo $message; // Use 234567 as otp to verify your mobile number.
```

See `\Magento\Framework\DataObject::toString()`